# opencv data to excel through xml storage?

Tags: xml, excel, opencv

I want to take some information from opencv program  and then store them in a file that after can be read though Microsoft excel program or even through openoffice and libreOffice.

the information that I need is a char variable that takes a value from a function that I wrote, and the other variable is double and represents a property that I take from the VideoCapture Class.

In the excel format I want to have a 2 row table that in the first position should be the videoCapture property(timestamp) and the other row to have the value of the char that I want.

My question is if this can happen though saving my data in a .xml or .yml format that I can do with the use of Opencv FileStorage Class in a way that my file is ready for reading through excel.

How do I need to save my data in the xml file ready to read from excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't.

The opencv xml format isn't very good, it cheats by putting all the elements on a line separated with spaces and then reads them back and interprets the image shape from the row/col members.

If you are writing large amounts of data (eg an image) I would create a simple function that outputs it as comma separated and import that. Or just output the cv::matrix with "<<" IIRC that space separates all the values in a row with a newline for each new row - Excel will import that easily